# Pseudoclass for Hovering Checked Checkbox (ChakraUI, React, NextJS Theme)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, chakra-ui

For some reason my styled checkbox still has the standard blue color whenever hovering over the checked Checkbox, I couldn't find anything about the relevant Pseudoclass Definition online.

Does anyone know what to use to style the Checkbox completely?

That's what I have so far:

```
variants: {
    regular: {},
    purple: {
      control: {
        /* borderColor: "#757575", */
        borderColor: "#ce93d8",
        bg: "transparent",
        borderWidth: "2",
        transition: "background-color 0.1s ease-in-out",
        _checked: {
          bg: "#ce93d8",
          borderColor: "#ce93d8",
        },
        _hover: {
          bg: "#616161",
          borderColor: "#ce93d8",
        },
        _active: {
          bg: "#ce93d8",
          borderColor: "#ce93d8",
        },
        _focus: {
          bg: "#ce93d8",
          borderColor: "#ce93d8",
        },
      },
    },
```

The _hover definition unfortunately doesn't change anything.